# Display 'increasing' if subsequent number of a sequence of integers is greater thant the previous

Tags: c

> Write a program that reads a sequence of integers and print 'increasing' if each subsequent number is greater than the previous, or print 'not increasing' otherwise. End of reading numbers ending is when you read a negative number.

Here's what I got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[100],i;

    for(i=0; ; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        if(a[i]<0)
            break;
    }

    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<0)
            break;

        if(a[i+1]>a[i])
        {
            printf("increasing\n");
        }
        else if(a[i+1]<a[i])
            printf("not increasing\n");
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

sample input: `1 4 6 2 6 3 -1`
sample output:

```
increasing
increasing
not increasing
increasing
not increasing
```

And I get:

```
increasing
increasing
not increasing
increasing
not increasing
not increasing
```

My question is how to remove the last unnecessary "not increasing"?

Comment: Please show the newlines in the output, to make it easier to read.

Comment: you compare `a[i]` with `a[i+1]`. you can also compare `a[i]` with `a[i-1]` if you start with 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Your code has another problem. You print "not increasing" only if `a[i+1]` is *strictly less* than `a[i]`. This is incorrect. The statement of the problem has a different requirement. It says that you have to print it "otherwise", i.e. when `a[i+1]` is *less or equal* to `a[i]`. In other words, your last `if` check is completely unnecessary. You have to print "not increasing" every time you take that `else` branch.

Comment: Also remember to handle a single negative input. Your current version handles that, but if you change it, it might not any more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple fix would be to change this test (in the second loop), from:

```
 if(a[i]<0)
    break;
```

to:

```
 if(a[i + 1]<0)
    break;
```

Note however that this is not very robust, but it's probably good enough for a simple homework exercise.

Comment: Thanks. It is good enough, because I am a beginner in C programming, and generally in programming. I appreciate the simple answer, it's all I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The program can be written simpler without using an array. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int prev, next;

    if ( scanf( "%d", &prev ) == 1 && prev >= 0 )
    {
        while ( scanf( "%d", &next ) == 1 && next >= 0 )
        {
            if ( next > prev ) printf( "increasing\n" );
            else printf( "not increasing\n" );

            prev = next;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter sequence of numbers

```
1 4 6 2 6 3 -1
```

then output will be

```
incresing
incresing
not increasing
incresing
not increasing
```

As for your code then in this statement

```
if(a[i+1]>a[i])
```

when `a[i]` is the last non-negative value then you are comparing it with the ended negarive number.

You could substitute this condition for

```
if( a[i]<0 || a[i+1] < 0 ) break;
```

Take into account that this expression

```
if( a[i+1] < 0 ) break;
```

is wrong because your sequence can have only one element and this element can be a negative number.:)

Comment: another advantage of this solution is that it will not crash if you enter more then 100 numbers....